# Top of the page whenever Refresh in Nextjs

Tags: next.js

On Refresh Top of the page.

Hii, I am trying to be on the top of the page whenever I referesh, in next js can someone help me?

This is the page.tsx in src/app location

```
`import Hero from "./hero"
import Feature21 from "./feature21"
import Feature22 from "./feature22"
import Feature23 from "./feature23"
import Feature24 from "./feature24"
import Feature25 from "./feature25"
import Feature26 from "./feature26"
import Stories from "./stories"
import OnePic from "./onePic"`

export default async function Home() {

  return (
    <div>
      <Hero />
      <Feature21 />
      <Feature22 />
      <Feature23 />
      <OnePic />
      <Feature24 />
      <Feature25 />
      <Feature26 />
      <Stories />
    </div>
  )
}
```